# Jekyll site fails only when pushed to GitHub

Tags: ruby, sass, jekyll, github-pages

I am developing a new version of a static website with Jekyll that deployed via Github pages: https://devcampy.com

The repository: https://github.com/gianarb/devcampy.com

Locally I run it with docker, and I am not able to reproduce the issue:

```
$ docker run --rm -p 4000:4000 -v "$PWD":/srv/jekyll jekyll/jekyll:stable jekyll serve
```

This is the error I get via email when I push to the repository. I can't figure out why it does not work properly

```
The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

Your SCSS file `assets/main.scss` has an error on line 6: File to import not found or unreadable: vendor/rfs. Load paths: node_modules /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.3/_sass /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.3/_sass /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.3/_sass. For more information, see https://help.github.com/en/articles/page-build-failed-invalid-sass-or-scss.
```

Does somebody have any feedback? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current bootstrap code is incomplete. 
**/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/vendor/_rfs.scss** is missing because of a **.gitignore** rule that prevent any **vendor** folder to be versioned.

1. In your **.gitignore**, replace `vendor` line by `vendor/bundle`
2. run `npm install bootstrap` to override current version

Comment: You can not imagine how much time I spent looking and thinking about this issue. thanks

Comment: It would have taken me two days to debug this, if I hadn't seen this answer.

Comment: While I'm not using npm and don't have a /node_modules folder, setting the gitignore rule in this way still resolved this issue with a missing `_sass/bootstrap/vendor/_rfs.scss`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling what the problem is. You have this on the line in main.scss

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

So this means the file may exist locally but is not able to import on your deploy since it's not there.

Looking at your repo I see you have bootstrap located here:

```
node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

So try this instead:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
// or you could try
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
```

I would think one of those should work.

Comment: Hello, it is not an import issue. The file exists and the jekyll scss plugin manages the base path as you can see in the _config.yaml https://github.com/gianarb/devcampy.com/blob/master/_config.yml#L12 . I tried your solution btw to double check and I get the same error. It also does not explain why locally it works fine both way

Comment: Now I know I should use this command more often `git check-ignore *`